# Decompress .tar file using wxStreams

Tags: c++, extract, wxwidgets, tar

I'm trying to decompress .tar using only default decompressing libraries avialable in wxWidgets.

My code:

```
//Creating empty dir?
    wxMkdir dir(dest_path2);

    wxFFileInputStream dirfile(dest_path2);

    wxZlibInputStream dirin(dirfile, wxZLIB_GZIP);

    dir.Write(dirin);
```

Comment: Did you try `wxTarInputStream`?

Comment: Oh, I'm such a dumbass, Of course i have to use wxTarInputStream to decompress TAR archive, i just thoughtlessly copied code from gzip decompression.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Creating empty dir
wxFFileOutputStream directory(dest_path2);

//Creating a decompression stream from a file
wxFFileInputStream tarfile2(dest_path);

//Decompress the data from stream
wxTarInputStream tarin(tarfile2,????);

//Saving stream decompressed files to directory
tarfile2.GetFile(tarin);

//Close
tarfile2.Close();
```

I don't understand the wxTarInputStream constructor

```
wxTarInputStream::wxTarInputStream(wxInputStream &stream,wxMBConv& conv =wxConvLocal );
```

Each subsequent file should be entered with GetNextEntry function?

```
wxTarEntry* wxTarInputStream::GetNextEntry();
```

I am not very good at using wxWidgets documentation yet, there are no examples of using at least one construct/function.

Comment: As explained in the docs, the `conv` parameter is used to interpret the file headers. You probably want to use `wxConvUTF8` here nowadays, but as long as the headers in your tar files only contain ASCII it doesn't really matter.